# How to pass argument in Sales Force label in Visual Page?

Tags: label

I Like to use custom label same way as I can use in Apex class. I like to use it in java script alerts/messages.
 My main concern is "How to pass some argument so that I can use it within java script code of VF" 
i.e. `string.format(System.Label.msg, new string[] {‘Label’}) <br />`

Where `Label.msg = 'Hello,  I am a {0}`

But I am not able to use it.

Comment: check this may  be worth reading


http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/32746/custom-labels-in-javascript

Comment: This does not fulfill my use case...... 
My use case … I have a form with 4 text box and I want to make blank validation using java script. I have created a method and I like to show alert message according to blank field. For that I like to create just single custom label, “{0} can not be blank” and in my code I pass field name as an argument and in Apex page there should be proper message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

{!$Label.YOUR_CUSTOM_LABEL_NAME}

Reference: https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_variables_global_label.htm

Comment: Thanks Vignex,

I am looking for “how to pass some argument to custom label ?” i.e. something like this 
{!$Label. CUSTOM_LABEL_NAME, ‘SOME_ARGUMENT’} and output should be same as it used in Apex class. Means output should be according to passed argument. 
For use case … Let I have a form with 4 text box and I want to make blank validation using java script. I have created a method and I like to show alert message according to blank field. For that I like to create just single custom label,  “{0} can not be blank” and in my code I pass field name as an argument.

Comment: @SanjayKharwar Custom label is just a text (with multi language support). It is not a function. You have to manually parse the text and replace with your value.