# How to add custom label in static resource JS alert

Tags: javascript, static-resources, customlabel

How to add custom label in static resource JS alert , i want to create a alert error message using a custom label in static resources

Comment: I believe this is what you are looking for- http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/32746/custom-labels-in-javascript

Comment: Custom label is not stored in static resources. Custom label is a different metadata type which can be accessed in Apex/Visualforce/Javascript directly.

Comment: but unable to do for alert

Comment: Please share your code

Answer (score 3):

If we need to access labels in JS file which is saved in static resource:
There are two way to do the same requiremnt:

1. Pass label as a parameter or pass-through attributes to JS function.
2. JavaScript bridging component:

2.a) loads before your script, like so:

```
<script>
    window.$Label = window.$Label || {};
    $Label.MyError = '{!JSENCODE($Label.MyError)}';
    $Label.MyPrompt = '{!JSENCODE($Label.MyPrompt)}';
    $Label.MyMessage = '{!JSENCODE($Label.MyMessage)}';
</script>
```

2.b) Now in your javascript (in a static resource) use the variables just as 
if they were VF without {!}

```
function errorHandler() {
    console.log($Label.MyError);
    alert($Label.MyMessage);
}
```

Comment: filesToUpload.length = 0;
   console.log('inside');
    _fadeOutFileUploadPopUp();
   $j("#closeButton").click;
   alert($Label.Easy_Archive_Storage_Space_Error);
   }
      } else {
          console.log(event.status);

Comment: @sudh When you add javascript in static resource you cannot access Custom Labels directly. As in the answer, you need to first store it in variables/constants and then JS in static resource can access these variables/constants.